# ASP.NET MVC progress indicator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, progress

How should I implement a progress indicator gif for an process which is importing data.

On the click of a button, the user browses the input file, selects and clicks on upload button. When the upload button is clicked the progress indicator gif should be displayed. If the file path is empty the progress indicator should not start. Is it possible to disable the page. I am using asp.net mvc 3

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a "busy" indicator with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355268/how-to-display-a-busy-indicator-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to do this unless you're using Ajax.  If you do, then you can simply show the animated gif before starting the ajax call, then hide it on success.

Comment: @AndyKash - see link above.

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

[ASP.Net MVC Loading In Progress Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287014/asp-net-mvc-loading-in-progress-indicator)

the idea is simple: create a div with the gif, show the div on the large process and hide the div after.